# How can I use a Workflow to email the document in a document library

Tags: workflow, attachments

We have a vendor who is not on our network and cannot access our 2010 SharePoint sites. I have a document library for that vendor with a subscription so that Reporting Services creates a report for that vendor and sends it to his document library. How can I use a workflow to send the report as an attachment to his email? (In the Field Data to Retrieve dialog, I can't find the document itself in the Field From Source dropdown. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done out of the box. But there is a solution on Codeplex that adds a custom workflow activity. This activity allows you to attach files that are either attachments in a list or documents in a library.

http://sharepointstuff.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check our [Send e-mail with attachments](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/actions-description/#SendEmail) workflow action workflow action also.

This workflow action is a part of [Workflow Actions Pack](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/) developed by my team. These actions work for SharePoint 2013 as well as for SharePoint Online (Office 365)

Comment: Anton, please be very clear that you are advertising your companies products in this post. It is ok to advertise them, but you need to make it obvious that you have connections to the products

Comment: Thank you for comment, I don't suggest my product unless I'm sure it can help. Possibly you didn't see it, but I mentioned workflow action as "Check our Send e-mail with attachment". It means I'm connected, but sure I will provide more information.

Comment: The PlumSail solution is $449/year (subscription).

Comment: You are right $449/year for ~100 workflow actions.